# 3 columns layout: fixed width, varying width, fill the remaining

Tags: html, css

I am creating a menu where I will have 3 columns. First one has a *fixed width*, third one have a *varying width* and the second one should *fill the remaining space*.

[image: Illustration]

So, I am facing two problems. First is, how do I get the middle box to fill the remaining space? and second, how do I get the links to stand next to each other with no fixed width?

Here is a code example.

```
<div id="menu">
    <div id="left">I am fixed</div>

    <div id="middle">
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="I should fill the remainder!" />
    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <div class="link">Link</div>
        <div class="link">Link</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wu493/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to reorder the columns as follows:

```html
<div id="menu">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
</div>
```

Then, you could set `margin-left` and `overflow-x` properties to the `#middle` to do the trick:

```css
#menu #left {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;    
}

#menu #middle {
    margin-left: 100px;  /* Push the #middle column 100px to the right       */
    overflow-x: hidden;  /* Prevent from getting behind of the right column  */
}

#menu #right {
    float: right;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wu493/1/)**.

Also, you had used `#link` selector to select the anchor tags, while the `link` is the class value, This would be fixed by using `#menu #right .link` instead.